# Show a custom Error page in jQuery on wrong URL

Tags: jquery, http-status-code-404

I have an application in web which is made by jQuery and HTML. Now if a user put any wrong url say www.abcd.com/menupa instead of www.abcd.com/menu I want to redirect it in my Custom Error page. I searched in web but did not find the solution.

Comment: Please also add your code.

Comment: Not possible in jQuery. You need a rewrite rule or error handling on the server unless all requests to any page goes via a landing page

Answer (score 0):

From jQuery API ajax docs:

```
error option
```

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: Please explain how to do this? @ user3629322

Comment: I think its not easy to do using jquery ,  So you can create a 404 error page via .htaccess

Comment: Please tell me how to do it via .htaccess @user3629322

Comment: Create a .htaccess file and upload this to root ,
Then add "ErrorDocument 404 /404.html" this line , Then create an 404.html page . When a 404 error become this 404.html automatically display,

Sorry my English is not good ,

Answer (score 0):

You can use .htaccess to do this :

```
ErrorDocument 404 "<H1>Page not found</H1>"
or
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

I think its easy to do.

Answer (score 0):

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

Create a file by copying above code but file name should be .htaccess and paste it in your website directory e.g   http://google.com/.htaccess